# Deleting zfs.img file in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, zfs, lxd

Under Ubuntu 16.04, is it safe to delete the file /var/lib/lxd/zfs.img that is taking up 10 Gb of space knowing that I am using lxd containers but only with the DIR storage backend and never used ZFS or even installed the zfs-utils package ?

Comment: See if it's part of a package: `dpkg -S /var/lib/lxd/zfs.img`.

Comment: It's doesn't seem so, your command returns:
`dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /var/lib/lxd/zfs.img`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you have a `zfs.img` image file while you have not installed the `zfsutils-linux` package. You are running LXD 2.0 (deb package) which requires the `zfsutils-linux` package in order to create a ZFS loop file.

To verify that ZFS it not used, run `sudo zfs list` and `sudo zpool list`. You should get *command not found*.

If you are sure that the ZFS loop file is not used, then you can move it to another location, and then reboot your computer. If LXD still works, then you are sure that the containers are not located in the ZFS loop file.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I thought and yes I've already tried `zfs list` and `zpool list` commands in the past and the result is _ command not found _

Comment: I don't know if it's worth mentioning but I recently updated LXD to 3.0.3 using the command `sudo apt install -t xenial-backports lxd lxd-client lxd-tools` and everything works fine but it doesn't explain the strange presence of this file which is by the way dated june 2016, about the time I commissioned the server and installed ubuntu. Anyway, just did what you suggested by moving the file and LXD is still working fine after restart. Thank you!